# How can I back up my GTA San Andreas iOS save if I need to reinstall it later?

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I want to temporarily uninstall GTA:SA from my iphone and I would like to save my progress on my computer (or phone). I want to know if there is a way to make a backup of my save file on the computer (or phone).

Comment: If you can find the save folder, you could copy it, put the copy somewhere else, then, when you want to get your save back, put the copy where the new save folder is. Finally, replace the contents of the save folder that comes with the game with the contents of the copy. (Hope I said that right...)

Comment: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-to-save-restore-iphone-ipad-game-progress-data-3534332/ might help to save GTA:SA progress on iPhone. Can't confirm if it works for that specific title, please update us if you test it.

Answer (score 1):

The save files are stored in a folder called "*GTA San Andreas User Files*", which can be found under "*My Documents*". It is also used to store your settings and other user files. The directory should stay in tact even if you uninstall the game, so after reinstalling it you can get back up to speed immediately.

To be safe, copy the directory with its contents somewhere safe.